# Mysql строковые функции и они же в php

Tags: функции, php, строки, mysql

Что работает быстрее: mysql строковые функции или они же в php?
Например есть задача: найти позицию вхождения подстроки в строке

Answer (score 1):

1. Насколько я знаю mysql может быть слегка побыстрее
2. Ключевое слово "слегка" - сильного увеличения производительности добиться врядли удастся.
3. В любом случае надо смотреть конкретный запрос.
4. Не стоит тратить время оптимизируя всякую фигню, надо найти узкое место и оптимизировать его.
5. Чем меньше логики ложится на базу, тем легче это все потом поддерживать.

Comment: Я просто пишу релевантный поиск с помощью like.
Чтобы не было кучи вопросов, поиск идет по названию товаров. Кто делал, тот, я думаю, понимает суть проблемы.
Если одно из слов есть (я проверяю позицию вхождения подстроки ) и если оно отличается от 0, то ставлю +1 к релевантности.
Хотя я видел пример, что используют и Like в выражении IF
Пример:
SELECT * , (IF(  `light_product_name` LIKE  "%nikon%", 1, 0 )...

И так, и так работает, потом протестирую на сколько отличается.